# Why for any $(n-l+1)$ orthogonal unit vectors $\{v_1,...v_{n-l+1}\}$ ,$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-l+1}a_{\alpha\beta}v^\alpha_iv^\beta_i\ge0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $V$ be a n-dimensional vector space,$A=\{a_{\alpha\beta}\} $ is a $n\times n$ antisymmetric matrix  ($A^T=-A$), and $rank A=l$.

Why for any $(n-l+1)$ orthogonal unit vectors $\{v_1,...v_{n-l+1}\}$ 
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-l+1}a_{\alpha\beta}v^\alpha_iv^\beta_i\ge0    ~~~~~~~~~~\alpha~\beta ~~\text{are summed up}
$$

Comment: Are the indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being summed up?

Comment: @Gustavo  Yes，you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.

Let $ \ V = \mathbb{R}^3$, $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$, $v_1 = (1,0,0) \ $ and $ \ v_2 = (0,1,0)$. Then $ \ n=3$, $Av_1 = -v_1,$ $Av_2 = -v_2$, $\ell = rank(A)=2$, $n- \ell +1 = 2 \ $ and $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-l+1}a_{\alpha\beta}v^\alpha_iv^\beta_i = Av_1 \bullet v_1 + Av_2 \bullet v_2 = (-1) + (-1) = -2 <0$$

Comment: If $A$ is antisymmetric , is it right ?

Comment: If $ \ A^T = -A$, then, $\forall v \in V$, we have $ \ Av \bullet v = - v \bullet Av = - Av \bullet v \ \Rightarrow \ Av \bullet v = 0$. So, the inequality is an equality and you can choose any vectors for the sum.

Comment: @lanse7pty The situation is this: without restrictions on $A$ it is false. Antisymmetry is too strong. What is a restriction on $A$ that will do, without being too strong?

Comment: @lanse7pty Hint: Identifying matrices with linear transformations we have that $ \ A: V \to V \ $ is linear and $ \ \ell = dim(im(A)) \ $ and $ \ n- \ell = dim(ker(A))$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think your question is useful for what I am thinking .

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that it helps.